# Missing library to reference OLEDB connection types

Tags: c#, ado.net, ssis, oledb

I got the following piece of code from [SSIS Team Blog](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/mattm/archive/2008/08/22/accessing-oledb-connection-managers-in-a-script.aspx) to cast the OLEDB connection type so that it can be used by the AcquireConnection () method. Now I am not sure why the Dts.Connections part is not working. I dont know the library that I would have to add to make it work. I pretty much added the most important ones including the Dts.RuntimeWrap. Please let me know if you need more information on the question.

```
ConnectionManager cm = Dts.Connections["oledb"];
Microsoft.SqlServer.Dts.Runtime.Wrapper.IDTSConnectionManagerDatabaseParameters100 cmParams = cm.InnerObject as Microsoft.SqlServer.Dts.Runtime.Wrapper.IDTSConnectionManagerDatabaseParameters100;
OleDbConnection conn = cmParams.GetConnectionForSchema() as OleDbConnection;
```

**EDIT**
Below is the entire code for this component.

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Data;
using System.Data.SqlClient;
using Microsoft.SqlServer.Dts.Runtime;
using System.Data.OleDb;
using System.Data.Common;
using System.Linq;
using System.Configuration;
using System.Collections;

//using System.Data.OleDb;

namespace AOC.SqlServer.Dts.Tasks
{

    [DtsTask(
        DisplayName = "Custom Logging Task",
        Description = "Writes logging info into a table")]
    public class CustomLoggingTask : Task
    {

        private string _packageName;
        private string _taskName;
        private string _errorCode;
        private string _errorDescription;
        private string _machineName;
        private double _packageDuration;

        private string _connectionName;
        private string _eventType;
        private string _executionid;
        private DateTime _handlerdatetime;
        private string _uid;
        public string ConnectionName
        {
            set
            {
                _connectionName = value;
            }
            get
            {
                return _connectionName;
            }
        }


        public string Event
        {
            set
            {
                _eventType = value;
            }
            get
            {
                return _eventType;
            }
        }

public override DTSExecResult Validate(Connections connections, VariableDispenser variableDispenser, IDTSComponentEvents componentEvents, IDTSLogging log)
        {
            const string METHOD_NAME = "CustomLoggingTask-Validate";

            try
            {

                if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(_eventType))
                {
                    componentEvents.FireError(0, METHOD_NAME, "The event property must be specified", "", -1);
                    return DTSExecResult.Failure;
                }


                if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(_connectionName))
                {
                    componentEvents.FireError(0, METHOD_NAME, "No connection has been specified", "", -1);
                    return DTSExecResult.Failure;
                }


                //SqlConnection connection = connections[_connectionName].AcquireConnection(null) as SqlConnection;
                DbConnection connection = connections[_connectionName].AcquireConnection(null) as DbConnection;

                ConnectionManager cm = Dts.Connections["oledb"];
                Microsoft.SqlServer.Dts.Runtime.Wrapper.IDTSConnectionManagerDatabaseParameters100 cmParams = cm.InnerObject as Microsoft.SqlServer.Dts.Runtime.Wrapper.IDTSConnectionManagerDatabaseParameters100;
                OleDbConnection conn = cmParams.GetConnectionForSchema() as OleDbConnection;



                if (connection == null)
                {
                    componentEvents.FireError(0, METHOD_NAME, "The connection is not a valid ADO.NET connection", "", -1);
                    return DTSExecResult.Failure;
                }

               if (!variableDispenser.Contains("System::SourceID"))
                {
                    componentEvents.FireError(0, METHOD_NAME, "No System::SourceID variable available. This task can only be used in an Event Handler", "", -1);
                    return DTSExecResult.Failure;
                }

                return DTSExecResult.Success;
            }
            catch (Exception exc)
            {
                componentEvents.FireError(0, METHOD_NAME, "Validation Failed: " + exc.ToString(), "", -1);
                return DTSExecResult.Failure;
            }
        }


public override DTSExecResult Execute(Connections connections, VariableDispenser variableDispenser, IDTSComponentEvents componentEvents, IDTSLogging log, object transaction)
       {
          try
            {
                string commandText =
@"INSERT INTO SSISLog (EventType, PackageName, TaskName, EventCode, EventDescription, PackageDuration, Host, ExecutionID, EventHandlerDateTime,UID)
VALUES (@EventType, @PackageName, @TaskName, @EventCode, @EventDescription, @PackageDuration, @Host, @Executionid, @handlerdatetime,@uid)";

                ReadVariables(variableDispenser);
                DbConnection connection = connections[_connectionName].AcquireConnection(transaction) as DbConnection;
                //SqlConnection connection = (SqlConnection)connections[_connectionName].AcquireConnection(transaction);
                DbCommand command = null;
                //using (SqlCommand command = new SqlCommand())
                if (connection is SqlConnection)
                    command = new SqlCommand();
                else if (connection is OleDbConnection)
                    command = new OleDbCommand();

                {
                    command.CommandText = commandText;
                    command.CommandType = CommandType.Text;
                    command.Connection = connection;

                    command.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("@EventType", _eventType));
                    command.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("@PackageName", _packageName));
                    command.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("@TaskName", _taskName));
                    command.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("@EventCode", _errorCode ?? string.Empty));
                    command.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("@EventDescription", _errorDescription ?? string.Empty));
                    command.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("@PackageDuration", _packageDuration));
                    command.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("@Host", _machineName));
                    command.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("@ExecutionID", _executionid));
                    command.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("@handlerdatetime", _handlerdatetime));
                    command.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("@uid", _uid));
                    command.ExecuteNonQuery();
                }
                connection.Close();
                return DTSExecResult.Success;

            }
            catch (Exception exc)
            {
                componentEvents.FireError(0, "CustomLoggingTask-Execute", "Task Errored: " + exc.ToString(), "", -1);
                return DTSExecResult.Failure;
            }

        }


        private void ReadVariables(VariableDispenser variableDispenser)
        {
            variableDispenser.LockForRead("System::StartTime");
            variableDispenser.LockForRead("System::PackageName");
            variableDispenser.LockForRead("System::SourceName");
            variableDispenser.LockForRead("System::MachineName");
            variableDispenser.LockForRead("System::ExecutionInstanceGUID");
            variableDispenser.LockForRead("System::EventHandlerStartTime");
            variableDispenser.LockForRead("User::UID");
            bool includesError = variableDispenser.Contains("System::ErrorCode");
            if (includesError)
            {
                variableDispenser.LockForRead("System::ErrorCode");
                variableDispenser.LockForRead("System::ErrorDescription");
            }

            Variables vars = null;
            variableDispenser.GetVariables(ref vars);

            DateTime startTime = (DateTime)vars["System::StartTime"].Value;
            _packageDuration = DateTime.Now.Subtract(startTime).TotalSeconds;
            _packageName = vars["System::PackageName"].Value.ToString();
            _taskName = vars["System::SourceName"].Value.ToString();
            _machineName = vars["System::MachineName"].Value.ToString();
            _executionid = vars["System::ExecutionInstanceGUID"].Value.ToString();
            _handlerdatetime = (DateTime)vars["System::EventHandlerStartTime"].Value;
            _uid = vars["User::UID"].Value.ToString();
            if (includesError)
            {
                _errorCode = vars["System::ErrorCode"].Value.ToString();
                _errorDescription = vars["System::ErrorDescription"].Value.ToString();
            }

            // release the variable locks.
            vars.Unlock();

            // reset the dispenser
            variableDispenser.Reset();
        }
    }

}
```

Comment: what error it throws? I tested the code you pointed out and seems correct.

Comment: I had a similar problem using Oledb connections. I gave up and just used ADO.net connections and stopped having those problems. Dont know if thats a possibility in your case though...

Comment: @Chopin. The error message that I get is "Error 1 The type or namespace name 'Connections' does not exist in the namespace 'AOC.SqlServer.Dts' (are you missing an assembly reference?)" I checked all my references and stuff but dont know what am I missing.

Comment: Mmm that's weird. Is your script task main class extending `Microsoft.SqlServer.Dts.Tasks.ScriptTask.VSTARTScriptObjectModelBase`? Can you show your script task' code?

Comment: This piece doesnt belong to a script task. I am trying to implement this inside a custom logging component. I am pasting the whole code as an edit.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

With the code you posted, I finally figured out what you were trying to accomplish.

These are the things I've done to get it to work:

**A)** The compile error you're receiving:

```
"Error 1 The type or namespace name 'Connections' does not exist in the namespace 'AOC.SqlServer.Dts' (are you missing an assembly reference?)"
```

is simply because the way you're trying to get the *oledb* connection manager:

```
ConnectionManager cm = Dts.Connections["oledb"];
```

The `Dts` object is a facility available in the script task component. You should replace that line with:

```
ConnectionManager cm = connections["oledb"];
```

I've seen in your code that you access a `Connection Manager` in this way, so maybe it was something you just left behind.

**B)** To validate if the connection manager is either an ADO.NET connection manager or an OLEDB one, changed this part of your code:

```
DbConnection connection = connections[_connectionName].AcquireConnection(null) as DbConnection;

ConnectionManager cm = Dts.Connections["oledb"];
Microsoft.SqlServer.Dts.Runtime.Wrapper.IDTSConnectionManagerDatabaseParameters100 cmParams = cm.InnerObject as Microsoft.SqlServer.Dts.Runtime.Wrapper.IDTSConnectionManagerDatabaseParameters100;
OleDbConnection conn = cmParams.GetConnectionForSchema() as OleDbConnection;

if (connection == null)
{
    componentEvents.FireError(0, METHOD_NAME, "The connection is not a valid ADO.NET connection", "", -1);
    return DTSExecResult.Failure;
}
```

First, added a private variable at the class level to store the connection:

```
private DbConnection _connection;
```

and then, modified the validation to check if the connection is ADO.NET, and in case it's not, to check if it's OLEDB:

```
_connection = connections[_connectionName].AcquireConnection(null) as DbConnection;

if (_connection == null)
{
    ConnectionManager cm = connections[_connectionName];
    Microsoft.SqlServer.Dts.Runtime.Wrapper.IDTSConnectionManagerDatabaseParameters100 cmParams = cm.InnerObject as Microsoft.SqlServer.Dts.Runtime.Wrapper.IDTSConnectionManagerDatabaseParameters100;
    _connection = cmParams.GetConnectionForSchema() as OleDbConnection;

    if (_connection == null)
    {
        componentEvents.FireError(0, METHOD_NAME, "The connection is not a valid ADO.NET or OLEDB connection", "", -1);
        return DTSExecResult.Failure;
    }
}
```

Note that I replaced the hardcoded `"oledb"` with the `_connectionName` variable, and also modified the error string when `_connection` is null in both cases.

**C)** To execute the command using an OLEDB provider were necesary the following changes:

- Use the new `_connection` variable, wich holds the previously retrieved connection.
- The parameters added to the command must be `OleDbParameter` instead of `SqlParameter`.
- The [OLE DB .NET Provider](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.oledb.oledbcommand.parameters.aspx) does not support named parameters. So, the `VALUES` part in the `INSERT` statement command needs to be modified to use `?`.

**D)** This is the complete working code:

```
using System;
using System.Data;
using System.Data.Common;
using System.Data.OleDb;
using System.Data.SqlClient;
using Microsoft.SqlServer.Dts.Runtime;

//using System.Data.OleDb;

namespace AOC.SqlServer.Dts.Tasks
{
    [DtsTask(
        DisplayName = "Custom Logging Task",
        Description = "Writes logging info into a table")]
    public class CustomLoggingTask : Task
    {
        private string _packageName;
        private string _taskName;
        private string _errorCode;
        private string _errorDescription;
        private string _machineName;
        private double _packageDuration;

        private string _connectionName;
        private string _eventType;
        private string _executionid;
        private DateTime _handlerdatetime;
        private string _uid;

        public string ConnectionName
        {
            set { _connectionName = value; }
            get { return _connectionName; }
        }

        public string Event
        {
            set { _eventType = value; }
            get { return _eventType; }
        }

        private DbConnection _connection;

        public override DTSExecResult Validate(Connections connections, VariableDispenser variableDispenser, IDTSComponentEvents componentEvents, IDTSLogging log)
        {
            const string METHOD_NAME = "CustomLoggingTask-Validate";

            try
            {
                if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(_eventType))
                {
                    componentEvents.FireError(0, METHOD_NAME, "The event property must be specified", "", -1);
                    return DTSExecResult.Failure;
                }

                if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(_connectionName))
                {
                    componentEvents.FireError(0, METHOD_NAME, "No connection has been specified", "", -1);
                    return DTSExecResult.Failure;
                }

                //SqlConnection connection = connections[_connectionName].AcquireConnection(null) as SqlConnection;
                _connection = connections[_connectionName].AcquireConnection(null) as DbConnection;

                if (_connection == null)
                {
                    ConnectionManager cm = connections[_connectionName];
                    Microsoft.SqlServer.Dts.Runtime.Wrapper.IDTSConnectionManagerDatabaseParameters100 cmParams = cm.InnerObject as Microsoft.SqlServer.Dts.Runtime.Wrapper.IDTSConnectionManagerDatabaseParameters100;
                    _connection = cmParams.GetConnectionForSchema() as OleDbConnection;

                    if (_connection == null)
                    {
                        componentEvents.FireError(0, METHOD_NAME, "The connection is not a valid ADO.NET or OLEDB connection", "", -1);
                        return DTSExecResult.Failure;
                    }
                }

                if (!variableDispenser.Contains("System::SourceID"))
                {
                    componentEvents.FireError(0, METHOD_NAME, "No System::SourceID variable available. This task can only be used in an Event Handler", "", -1);
                    return DTSExecResult.Failure;
                }

                return DTSExecResult.Success;
            }
            catch (Exception exc)
            {
                componentEvents.FireError(0, METHOD_NAME, "Validation Failed: " + exc.ToString(), "", -1);
                return DTSExecResult.Failure;
            }
        }

        public override DTSExecResult Execute(Connections connections, VariableDispenser variableDispenser, IDTSComponentEvents componentEvents, IDTSLogging log, object transaction)
        {
            try
            {
                string commandText = null;

                ReadVariables(variableDispenser);
                //DbConnection connection = connections[_connectionName].AcquireConnection(transaction) as DbConnection;
                //SqlConnection connection = (SqlConnection)connections[_connectionName].AcquireConnection(transaction);
                DbCommand command = null;

                //using (SqlCommand command = new SqlCommand())
                if (_connection is SqlConnection)
                {
                    commandText = @"INSERT INTO SSISLog (EventType, PackageName, TaskName, EventCode, EventDescription, PackageDuration, Host, ExecutionID, EventHandlerDateTime,UID)
                                    VALUES (@EventType, @PackageName, @TaskName, @EventCode, @EventDescription, @PackageDuration, @Host, @Executionid, @handlerdatetime,@uid)";

                    command = new SqlCommand();

                    command.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("@EventType", _eventType));
                    command.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("@PackageName", _packageName));
                    command.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("@TaskName", _taskName));
                    command.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("@EventCode", _errorCode ?? string.Empty));
                    command.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("@EventDescription", _errorDescription ?? string.Empty));
                    command.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("@PackageDuration", _packageDuration));
                    command.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("@Host", _machineName));
                    command.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("@ExecutionID", _executionid));
                    command.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("@handlerdatetime", _handlerdatetime));
                    command.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("@uid", _uid));
                }
                else if (_connection is OleDbConnection)
                {
                    commandText = @"INSERT INTO SSISLog (EventType,PackageName,TaskName,EventCode,EventDescription,PackageDuration,Host,ExecutionID,EventHandlerDateTime,UID)
                                    VALUES (?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?)";

                    command = new OleDbCommand();

                    command.Parameters.Add(new OleDbParameter("@EventType", _eventType));
                    command.Parameters.Add(new OleDbParameter("@PackageName", _packageName));
                    command.Parameters.Add(new OleDbParameter("@TaskName", _taskName));
                    command.Parameters.Add(new OleDbParameter("@EventCode", _errorCode ?? string.Empty));
                    command.Parameters.Add(new OleDbParameter("@EventDescription", _errorDescription ?? string.Empty));
                    command.Parameters.Add(new OleDbParameter("@PackageDuration", _packageDuration));
                    command.Parameters.Add(new OleDbParameter("@Host", _machineName));
                    command.Parameters.Add(new OleDbParameter("@ExecutionID", _executionid));
                    command.Parameters.Add(new OleDbParameter("@handlerdatetime", _handlerdatetime));
                    command.Parameters.Add(new OleDbParameter("@uid", _uid));
                }

                command.CommandText = commandText;
                command.CommandType = CommandType.Text;
                command.Connection = _connection;

                command.ExecuteNonQuery();
                _connection.Close();
                return DTSExecResult.Success;

            }
            catch (Exception exc)
            {
                componentEvents.FireError(0, "CustomLoggingTask-Execute", "Task Errored: " + exc.ToString(), "", -1);
                return DTSExecResult.Failure;
            }
        }

        private void ReadVariables(VariableDispenser variableDispenser)
        {
            variableDispenser.LockForRead("System::StartTime");
            variableDispenser.LockForRead("System::PackageName");
            variableDispenser.LockForRead("System::SourceName");
            variableDispenser.LockForRead("System::MachineName");
            variableDispenser.LockForRead("System::ExecutionInstanceGUID");
            variableDispenser.LockForRead("System::EventHandlerStartTime");
            variableDispenser.LockForRead("User::UID");
            bool includesError = variableDispenser.Contains("System::ErrorCode");
            if (includesError)
            {
                variableDispenser.LockForRead("System::ErrorCode");
                variableDispenser.LockForRead("System::ErrorDescription");
            }

            Variables vars = null;
            variableDispenser.GetVariables(ref vars);

            DateTime startTime = (DateTime)vars["System::StartTime"].Value;
            _packageDuration = DateTime.Now.Subtract(startTime).TotalSeconds;
            _packageName = vars["System::PackageName"].Value.ToString();
            _taskName = vars["System::SourceName"].Value.ToString();
            _machineName = vars["System::MachineName"].Value.ToString();
            _executionid = vars["System::ExecutionInstanceGUID"].Value.ToString();
            _handlerdatetime = (DateTime)vars["System::EventHandlerStartTime"].Value;
            _uid = vars["User::UID"].Value.ToString();
            if (includesError)
            {
                _errorCode = vars["System::ErrorCode"].Value.ToString();
                _errorDescription = vars["System::ErrorDescription"].Value.ToString();
            }

            // release the variable locks.
            vars.Unlock();

            // reset the dispenser
            variableDispenser.Reset();
        }
    }
}
```

Just for the record, I leave you some links that I've found useful for develop, deploy and debug custom components (but maybe you have already went through them!):

http://bennyaustin.wordpress.com/2009/06/30/steps-to-build-and-deploy-custom-ssis-components/

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms403356%28v=sql.105%29.aspx

http://toddmcdermid.blogspot.com.ar/2009/06/converting-your-script-task-into-custom_22.html

Cheers.

Comment: Thanks for sharing your knowledge. I am really glad to see this working :) Thank you!!!!

Comment: To be very honest, I didnt know of a way of changing the code. I tried really hard to get it to work, but I lack any sort of extensive C# knowledge and hence, I had to post the bounty. I stepped through the code again and all of it now makes a lot more sense!

Comment: No problem! The important thing is, that you have understood how it works rather than just copy & paste it in your solution. As for the bounty, I think it will be awarded automatically to me, if you don't :)

Comment: Awarded the bounty! Didnt know I had to click that button. Thanks for the help again.

Comment: And by doing so, you've earned the _Benefactor_ badge! ^^