# How to access OLEDB Connection Manager in SSIS script task

Tags: ssis, ssis-2012, ssis-2008

I am new to SSIS script task, I tried the below code to run a sql query in SSIS script task but I am end up with an error.

```
ConnectionManager cm = Dts.Connections["oledb"]; 
IDTSConnectionManagerDatabaseParameters100 cmParams = cm.InnerObject as IDTSConnectionManagerDatabaseParameters100; 
OleDbConnection sqlConn = cmParams.GetConnectionForSchema() as OleDbConnection;
```

ErrorMessage:

> Unable to cast COM object of type 'System.__ComObject' to class type
>   'System.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnection'.  Instances of types that
>   represent COM components cannot be cast to types that do not represent
>   COM components;  however they can be cast to interfaces as long as the
>   underlying COM component supports QueryInterface calls for the IID of
>   the interface

I am trying to find DB Server name and try to assign the value to $Project::variable using Script task.

Is there anyway I can do this.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: "I am trying to find DB Server name and try to assign the value to $Project::variable using Script task.". You're doing this backwards. You should be defining the server name in a project or package parameter, then applying that to your connection manager.

Comment: Also, parameters, project and package, are read only during execution

Comment: You may want to refer to this I guess [OLEDB And Ado.net within script task](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11265706/missing-library-to-reference-oledb-connection-types)

Comment: @Nick.McDermaid: Our Server has "Always on" enabled. We are connecting the DB using Listener. I can't assign the server name directly in the project parameter. If i do so then it would be static.

Comment: @rvphx: I googled and tried all possible scenarios, but no luck.

Comment: It’s wise to explain the full story first time. Normally you connect to the listener (which is static) then it decides where to redirect you.